# Is it possible to compile a .ipa from a package stored in an iOS simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I've recently managed to lose a project I've been working on alone, I realise that I should be better at backing up and I should have been using a remote repo.

The app is still installed on one of my simulators, so I'm wondering if it's possible to use the package stored on their to create an .ipa file?

Comment: I guess no, simulator ipa are build fro x86 architectures, while iPhone or iPad fro ARM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible to create an IPA using the stored container from simulator.